# MATLAB script with accented characters does not work correctly with UTF-8 listing

Tags: pdftex, listings

I am truly desperate. I need accented characters in the MATLAB script. I wouldn't mind with comments, but accents are also in Figures, which does actually matter. Both `.tex` file and `.m` file are saved in UTF-8 encoding (both natively, as I configured MATLAB to use UTF-8 encoding from startup). Yet `pdflatex` still somehow thinks there are invalid byte sequences, which I in fact verified is false.

This is my preamble:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    detect-family,
    detect-inline-family=math,
    group-separator={ },
    group-minimum-digits={3},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}

%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{
    extendedchars=\true,                    % Use extended charset
    inputencoding=utf8,                     % Use input encoding UTF-8
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},          % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,              % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,                % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                        % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                           % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},         % comment style
    deletekeywords={...},                   % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},                 % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,                     % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    firstnumber=1000,                       % start line enumeration with line 1000
    frame=single,                           % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                        % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              % keyword style
    language=MATLAB,                        % the language of the code
    morekeywords={*,...},                   % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    numbers=left,                           % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                          % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},      % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},                % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                       % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,                 % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                         % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=2,                           % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},         % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                              % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    caption=\texttt{\protect\filename@parse{\lstname}\protect\filename@base.\protect\filename@ext}
                                            % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

I am trying to import the MATLAB script file contents with this line:

```tex
\lstinputlisting{files/source/cast1.m}
```

This is what my LaTeX compiler says about the MATLAB script:

```
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "8C.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "8D.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "A1.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "9B.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "AD.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte "AD.
...
```

Screenshot of the actual error messages:
[image: MATLAB seems to have encoding error]

However file encoding shows no UTF-8 errors in validation:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 files/source/cast1.m -o /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

And this is contents of the MATLAB script:

```matlab
%% Projekt: POL0423 [Část I]
clc; close all; clear all;          % Vyčištění pracovní plochy

%% 01: Část I.A - Zadané parametry

% Průřezy
A_0 = 15.9;                         % [m^2]             průřez nádoby
A_2 = 2.595;                        % [m^2]             průřez odtoku

% Koeficienty přítoku
Q_A = 15;                           % [m^3 * s^(-1)]    přítok poč.
Q_B = 29;                           % [m^3 * s^(-1)]    přítok mod.
Q_C = 11.5;                         % [m^3 * s^(-1)]    přítok ust.

% Časové koficienty
t_A = 36;                           % [s]               čas skok. změny
t_B = 81;                           % [s]               čas snižování
t_C = 176;                          % [s]               čas ustálení

% Fyzikální konstanty
g = 9.81;                           % [m * s^(-2)]      tíhové zrychlení

% Diferenciální rovnice
% A_0 * dh(t)/dt = Q_1(t) - Q_2(t) = Q_1(t) - A_2 * sqrt(2gh(t))

%% 02: Část I.B - Sestavení modelu
modelB = sim('cast1_model_B');          % Simulink: simulace modelu

% Načtení dat a uložení do samostatných proměnných

% Vstupní proměnná
Scope_Q1_tB = modelB.Scope_Q1_modelB.time;              % Čas
Scope_Q1_wB = modelB.Scope_Q1_modelB.signals.values;    % Přítok

% Výstupní proměnná
Scope_h_tB = modelB.Scope_h_modelB.time;                % Čas
Scope_h_wB = modelB.Scope_h_modelB.signals.values;      % Hladina

%% 03: Část I.C - Linearizace modelu
u_0 = Q_C                           % Ustálený přítok
h_0 = (Q_C / A_2)^2 * 1/(2*g)       % Ustálená hladina

% Matice linearizovaného modelu
A = [ (-sqrt(2) * A_2 * sqrt(g))/(2 * A_0 * sqrt(h_0)) ]
B = [ 1/A_0 ]
C = [ 1 ]
D = [ 0 ]

[lin_nom,lin_den] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D);     % Převod do vnějšího popisu
G_lin = tf(lin_nom,lin_den);

modelC = sim('cast1_model_C');          % Simulink: simulace modelu

% Výstupní proměnná
Scope_h_tC = modelC.Scope_h_modelC.time;                % Čas
Scope_h_wC = modelC.Scope_h_modelC.signals.values;      % Hladina

% Vykreslení grafů
figure
plot(Scope_Q1_tB, Scope_Q1_wB)
grid on
range=ylim();
ylim([0 range(2)])
title('Přítok Q_1(t)')
xlabel('$t$ [s]','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$Q_1(t)$ [$\mathrm{m}^3 \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1}$]',...
    'interpreter','latex')

figure
plot(Scope_h_tB, Scope_h_wB, Scope_h_tC, Scope_h_wC)
grid on
title('Hladina h(t)')
legend('Nelineární model','Linearizovaný model')
xlabel('$t$ [s]','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$h(t)$ [m]','interpreter','latex')

%% 04: Část I.D - Zvýšení přítoku a porovnání s linearizovaným modelem
modelD = sim('cast1_model_D');          % Simulink: simulace modelu

% Vstupní proměnná
Scope_Q1_tD = modelD.Scope_Q1_modelD.time;              % Čas
Scope_Q1_wD = modelD.Scope_Q1_modelD.signals.values;    % Přítok

% Výstupní proměnná
Scope_h_tD_nelin = modelD.Scope_h_modelD_nelin.time;    % Čas
Scope_h_wD_nelin = modelD.Scope_h_modelD_nelin.signals.values;
                                                        % Hladina

Scope_h_tD_lin = modelD.Scope_h_modelD_lin.time;        % Čas
Scope_h_wD_lin = modelD.Scope_h_modelD_lin.signals.values;
                                                        % Hladina

% Vykreslení grafů
figure
plot(Scope_Q1_tD, Scope_Q1_wD)
grid on
range=ylim();
ylim([0 range(2)])
title('Přítok Q_1(t)')
xlabel('$t$ [s]','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$Q_1(t)$ [$\mathrm{m}^3 \cdot \mathrm{s}^{-1}$]',...
    'interpreter','latex')

figure
plot(Scope_h_tD_nelin, Scope_h_wD_nelin, Scope_h_tD_lin, Scope_h_wD_lin)
grid on
title('Hladina h(t)')
legend('Nelineární model','Linearizovaný model')
xlabel('$t$ [s]','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$h(t)$ [m]','interpreter','latex')

%% 05: Uložení parametrů a výpočtů
save('save_param',...
    't_A','t_B','t_C',...
    'Q_A','Q_B','Q_C',...
    'A_0','A_2',...
    'g',...
    'A','B','C','D',...
    'u_0','h_0')
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is hapenning? Did I overlook something?

Comment: listings splits utf8 chars in bytes while processing the code and this breaks them. You can try listingsutf8, but normally it is better to define the output of the accented chars with the literate option of listings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, neighter seems to work. If you look into the preamble, you'll see that I'm already using `listingsutf8` package. The original `listings` package is commented out.

Comment: Well as I wrote: the literate option normally works better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So what do you suggest me to do with the MATLAB script file? If the package splits it up to individual bytes, then the literate option won't work eighter, because the file is in UTF-8 encoding. I would have to convert it to Windows 1250 encoding (Central European encoding), specify it's in this encoding, and then specify literate option, right? Not only that, I would actually have to delete UTF-8 configuration statup script because MATLAB will overwrite the file with UTF-8 encoding again otherwise. Do you have an idea how can I solve the issue while remaining fully in UTF-8?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use `pdflatex`? I just tried your example in `xelatex`, and it works just fine there.

Comment: @chsk I'm using Visual Studio LaTeX Workstation Tool plugin, which I'm not sure if it does in fact contain `xelatex` package. Not a problem, I can install it. But, does it produce PDF straight out? I'm not sure if PostScript supports embedded files, and I have files embedded in the PDF. Also, PDF is a required format to submit the document.

Comment: @Polda18 yes, `xelatex` produces PDF files. I've no experience with Visual Studio and its plugins, but it might be worth investigating if this is a viable option.

Comment: the literate option can replace n bytes by m other bytes. So it doesn't care about utf8. There are enought example here how to use it (and how to use it with utf8 encoded files)

Comment: @chsk @UlrikeFischer Okay, then I'll try out literate option first and then if it doesn't work, the `xelatex`. Thanks guys 

Comment: I need to work with Czech characters and replace them with composite letters in the final version. Is there some automatic option I can use instead of manually setting up composite letters for each Czech character? The accented characters used in Czech language are these ones: `[ěščřžýáíéóúůňďťĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉÓÚŮŇĎŤ]`.

Comment: Okay, `xelatex` does in fact solve the listing issue, but now I cannot use `attachfile` package, which only works with `pdflatex`. I need to attach files to the PDF. Not only the source codes, but also other files, which are actually in binary format. I'm REALLY desperate now :(

Comment: ```attachfile works _only_ with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(attachfile) and _only_ in PDF-generating mode. For this run,
(attachfile) placeholders will be substituted for all
(attachfile) attachfile commands.
```

Comment: Not to mention that only one Czech character from imported listing really works with `xelatex`, others are completely stripped out. Not gonna work eighter.

Comment: I ended up replacing all accented characters inside source files with default ASCII characters. I need this to be working, and neighter `xelatex` nor `pdflatex` seems to work with Czech accents correctly, `xelatex` doesn't even support file attachments, which is crucial part for me actually. I'm gonna flag a bug report to LaTeX Workstation VSCode plugin devs, which is what I'm using to write the document in. Thanks for your help anyway. Feel free to bounty this, if anyone knows a working solution, I'll be happy to listen. For now, I'm gonna use whatever I need to produce a working document.

Comment: An update: I decided to place Czech characters back and experiment around various settings. The key thing is this: `extendedchars=true, % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8` - That means that `extendedchars` doesn't work with UTF-8 charset, it needs an 8-bit encoding. `listingsutf8` package seems to convert an input file into an 8-bit encoding (if it is viable, which it should be with Central European charset). However I must be doing something wrong :( The correct 8-bit encoding for CE is `CP1250` (Windows). Do I need to escape accents?

Comment: I also tried fooling around with `minted` package, but I'm not happy with the end result. Not only are there limited options to customize the listing, the entire listing doesn't get split amongst multiple pages if it doesn't fit in, it just kind of continues outside the page, and there seems no way to override this behaviour. So I would like to stick with the original `listingsutf8` package and `\lstinputlisting` command.

Comment: Okay, so in the end I actually ended up using the `literate` option, I realised I just forgot to include every single character and therefore some have been missed. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I ended up doing, finally solving my issue. I added `extendedchars=true` option back to the listings settings, and I realised that I forgot to include some of the characters. As soon as I included them, the issue was gone.

This is now my `listingsutf8` settings in preamble:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

% ...

\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset{
    %inputencoding=utf8,                    % Use input encoding UTF-8
    extendedchars=true,                     % Use extended character set
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},          % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,              % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,                % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                        % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=t,                           % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},         % comment style
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},                 % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    firstnumber=1,                          % start line enumeration with line 1000
    frame=single,                           % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                        % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              % keyword style
    language=MATLAB,                        % the language of the code
    morekeywords={*,...},                   % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    numbers=left,                           % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                          % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},      % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},                % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                       % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,                 % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                         % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=1,                           % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},         % string literal style
    tabsize=4,                              % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    caption=\texttt{\protect\filename@parse{\lstname}\protect\filename@base.\protect\filename@ext},
                                            % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
    literate=                               % Replace Czech characters with composite letters counterpart
                                            % áÁ čČ ďĎ éÉ ěĚ íÍ ňŇ óÓ řŘ šŠ ťŤ úÚ ůŮ
    {á}{{\'{a}}}1 {Á}{{\'{A}}}1 {č}{{\v{c}}}1 {Č}{{\v{C}}}1
    {ď}{{\v{d}}}1 {Ď}{{\v{D}}}1 {é}{{\'{e}}}1 {É}{{\'{E}}}1
    {ě}{{\v{e}}}1 {Ě}{{\v{E}}}1 {í}{{\'{i}}}1 {Í}{{\'{I}}}1
    {ň}{{\v{n}}}1 {Ň}{{\v{N}}}1 {ó}{{\'{o}}}1 {Ó}{{\'{O}}}1
    {ř}{{\v{r}}}1 {Ř}{{\v{R}}}1 {š}{{\'{s}}}1 {Š}{{\'{S}}}1
    {ť}{{\v{t}}}1 {Ť}{{\v{T}}}1 {ú}{{\'{u}}}1 {Ú}{{\'{U}}}1
    {ů}{{\r{u}}}1 {Ů}{{\r{U}}}1 {ž}{{\v{z}}}1 {Ž}{{\v{Z}}}1
    {ý}{{\'{y}}}1 {Ý}{{\'{Y}}}1
}

% ...
```

And the listings in my document now look like this:
[image]

Thank you and sorry for my rather stupid behaviour. I missed what the compiler actually told me, or rather said didn't quite understand it. Now I know I need to replace Unicode characters with their composite counterparts. Not sure how that would work with let's say Arabic or Chinese, but that's a whole different issue and I don't think I'll ever encounter that issue with these *thousands characters* languages. This is quite bulky workaround, that however works for my needs. Doesn't need to be pretty.